# WPF RichTextBox: Disable Dragging Text within , Allow Dragging Text outside

Tags: wpf, text, richtextbox, drag

I have a UserControl with a RichTextBox in it. It must be disallowed to drag/drop Text within the RichTextBox so the user can not change the visible sort order of the strings in the RichTextBox.

But... it must be allowed to the user to drag/drop Text outside the UserControl to the same kubd if the UserControl.

Is that somehow possible?